# Select query for frozen list Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to write a cassandra query for searching data in frozen list below is my table. Thanks in advance

```
deviceid           | streamid | datalist
--------------------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0x236A906D3F4CDB72 |      110 | [{date: '2018-09-26 11:49:52.295000+0000', values: '30AEA4807704,-74'}, {date: '2018-09-26 11:49:54.232000+0000', values: '30AEA4807704,-74'}, {date: '2018-09-26 11:50:22.531000+0000', values: '30AEA4807704,-73'}, {date: '2018-09-26 11:50:24.538000+0000', values: '30AEA4807704,-73'}, {date: '2018-10-04 05:54:48.189000+0000', values: '30AEA4807704,-73'}, {date: '2018-10-04 05:55:55.243000+0000', values: '30AEA4807704,-73'}]
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to query? Could you also share your table definition?

Comment: and query that you're trying to write

Answer (score 0):

You can not search on data that is in the frozen list.